# Least square solution to a problem of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, least-squares, block-matrices

Let $A$ be a $m\times m$ full rank matrix given by
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
R & w \\
0 & v
\end{bmatrix}, \quad R\in \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}, \quad w\in\mathbb{R}^k, \quad v\in\mathbb{R}^{m-k}.$$
If $b$ is a $m\times 1$ matrix given by
$$
b=\begin{bmatrix}
c \\
d
\end{bmatrix},\quad c\in\mathbb{R}^k,\quad d\in\mathbb{R}^{m-k},
$$
I need to prove that
$$
\min ||Ax-b||=||d||^2-\left(\frac{v^Td}{||v||}\right)^2.
$$

What I did is, considering the normal equation $$A^TAx=A^Tb,$$ we must have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
R^TR & R^Tw \\
w^TR & ||w||^2+||v||^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
R^Tc  \\
w^Tc+v^Td
\end{bmatrix},
$$
with $x_1\in \mathbb{R}^k,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$. So,
$$
\begin{cases}
R^TRx_1+R^Twx_2=R^Tc \\
w^TRx_1+(||w||^2+||v||^2)x_2=w^Tc+v^Td.
\end{cases}
$$

Maybe I could group this equations in a way that uses the normal equations for $R^T, w^T$ and $v^T$, like
$$
\begin{cases}
R^T(Rx_1+wx_2)=R^Tc \\
w^T(Rx_1+wx_2)+v^T(vx_2)=w^Tc+v^Td,
\end{cases}
$$
but I don't know if this is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach. Multiplying the first equation (from the left) by $w^TR^{-T}$ and subtracting the result from the second equation yields a result that simplifies to
$$
\|v\|^2 x_2 = v^Td \implies x_2 = \frac{v^Td}{v^Tv}.
$$
Substituting into the first equation yields
$$
R^TR x_1 = - x_2 R^T w + R^Tc \implies\\
Rx_1 = -x_2 w + c \implies \\
x_1 = R^{-1}(c - x_2w). 
$$
Now, the corresponding vector $Ax$ is given by
$$
Ax = \pmatrix{R & w\\0 & v} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2} = \pmatrix{Rx_1 + wx_2\\ x_2v} = \pmatrix{c-x_2w+x_2w\\x_2v} = 
\pmatrix{c \\
\frac{v^Td}{v^Tv}v}.
$$
It is straightforward to compute $\|Ax - b\|$ from there.